# CSS animated button won't animate when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a button to trigger nav menu to open (this is placed in the top right corner). When you open the menu (by clicking the button) it works as intended - menu is open and button animates.

It also works when you click the icon again - Then it closes the menu and animates the icon back to it's initial position.

But when you have the menu open and click outside the icons area it closes the menu BUT the icon doesn't animate.

**How can I get the icon to animate back to initial position, when a click outside has been made?**

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq23tvov/)

And here is the script:

```
 $(function() {
   var btn = $('#btn');
   menu = $('nav ul');
   menuHeight = menu.height();

   $(btn).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
   });

   $('html').on("click touchstart", function() {
    menu.slideUp();
   });

   $('.nav-wrapper').on("click touchstart", function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
   });

   $( "#nav-toggle" ).on( "click", function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
   }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your JS: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bfvq5Lp/)

```
$('html').on("click touchstart", function() {
    menu.slideUp();
    $('#nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
});
```